# Which preposition should I use in the sentence "move the cursor * 2 pixels"?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition should I use in the sentence "move the cursor * 2 pixels"?
And maybe I should use 'shift' or anything else, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No preposition is required.

> Move the cursor two pixels.

You can add a direction:

> Move the cursor two pixels left.